# Is the string == overloaded operator actually used in some generic comparison method?

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I am currently reading Jon Skeet's `C# in Depth, 2nd Edition`. I'd like to quote listing 3.5:

```
static bool AreReferencesEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T : class
{
    return first == second;
}
...
string name = "John";
string intro1 = "My name is " + name;
string intro2 = "My name is " + name;
Console.WriteLine(intro1 == intro2);
Console.WriteLine(AreReferencesEqual(intro1, intro2);
```

The author writes that the output should be `True` for the first comparison and `False` for the second one, because the overloaded operator is not used in the generic method. And he is, of course, right about the output.

Now let's change the code snippet a little bit:

```
static bool AreReferencesEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T : class
{
    return first == second;
}
...
string intro1 = "John";
string intro2 = "John";
Console.WriteLine(intro1 == intro2);
Console.WriteLine(AreReferencesEqual(intro1, intro2);
```

Now both methods of comparing return `True`. Let's tweak the code again, because this might have something to do with the fact that previously we compared variables that were created using an already existing `string`.

```
static bool AreReferencesEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T : class
{
    return first == second;
}
...
string name = "John"
string intro1 = name;
string intro2 = name;
Console.WriteLine(intro1 == intro2);
Console.WriteLine(AreReferencesEqual(intro1, intro2);
```

The output is `True` in both situations.

Can anyone clarify what are the reasons for such behavior? Is there really such big of a difference between examples one and three?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1061627/497356. Also string interning might be helpful to understand in answering your question

Comment: It's worth clarifying whether your question is *actually* about the differences between examples 1 and 3, or whether it's about "why the string == overloaded operator is *not* used in generic comparison method" (to correct your title to match reality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals in C# are interned, which is to say all uses of equal string literals result in a single string instances with references to that string throughout the application.  Your generic method is indeed using the `object` overload of the `==` operator, as Jon says, but despite the fact that you're using the `object` overload you're passing the same reference for both parameters.  In Jon's original example he goes out of his way to prevent the strings from being interned (by computing them at runtime) and thus ensuring that he has two different string instances, with separate references, that happen to represent the same sequence of characters.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a massive difference.

In example 1, `intro1` and `intro2` refer to different objects. In examples 
2 and 3, `intro1` and `intro2` have the same value - they refer to the same object, so if you call `Object.ReferenceEquals(intro1, intro2)` that will return true.

The reason for the behaviour is that the compiler has to work out what `==` means in `AreReferencesEqual` at compile-time, without knowing the value of `T`. It can't tell that you're going to call it with a type argument of `string`, so it doesn't know about the overload of `==`. It's basically the same reason you couldn't call any other string-specific members in `AreReferencesEqual`.

Comment: It's curious that it requires `name` to be `const` in a concatenation situation for it to refer to the same object. I would've thought that such a basic scenario would lead the compiler to the same object.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I suspect it would very rarely be of benefit in real life vs contrived scenarios.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If `name` were `const` the strings in the first example would indeed be computed at compile time, and would therefore be interned.